# Rails static page routes vs :constraints => { :url => /.+/ } -- pros and cons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm creating Page admin setup. Pages may include sub pages and I have a bunch of functionality to create the trailing url strings. Anyways, just wondering what the pros and cons here is. Speed-wise or anything I didn't really consider (aside maybe a bit more/less flexibility with other route matching):

**Option 1 -- Match everything to pages:**

```
get ':url' => 'pages#show', :constraints => { :url => /.+/ }
# with @page = Page.find_by_url("/"+params[:url]) in my controller
```

**Option 2 -- Statically map routes to pages, and reload routes after each save**

```
if Page.table_exists? # Otherwise on rake db:migrate this file will be called and throw an error
  Page.all.each do |page|
    match page.url, :controller => 'pages', :action => 'show', :page_id => page.id
  end
end
# Then after pages save it calls MyApp::Application.reload_routes!
```

Either way may work just as well.. just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Option-1 is superior and will actually work properly regardless of your deployment environment, Option-2 will fail in any non-trivial deployment.

Suppose you have two web server processes, **P1** and **P2**; they may be on the same machine, separate machines, or perhaps in separate VMs on the same machine. Suppose some saves a new page that just happens to go to **P1**; then **P1** will update the database (a shared resource between **P1** and **P2**) and rebuild its routing table. But now **P1** has the correct routing information but **P2** is stuck with the old one because no one told it that something had changed.

You could set up some polling or broadcast system but that would just be a bunch of pointless complexity when Option-1 will work just fine as-is.

Comment: Yeah good point. I wouldn't have done that. But yeah Option 1 uses less dependency and quite a bit simpler. I suppose speed may be the other thing.. but I'm sure it's just as quick.. finding an id vs a url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use routes constraints:

```
 get ':url' => 'pages#show', :constraints => lambda {|request| Page.all.map(&:url).include?(request.path[1..-1]) }
```

Can yet to use a "catch all" to "page not found"

```
get '*not_found' => 'page#not_found'
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints